# Image (UIImage) orientation changes when loading in UIIMageView or switching cameras

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm facing this orientation problem in 2 scenarios in my app.

1. View Controller loads > `TensorFlow` initializes > `UIImage` is set to a `UIImageView`
2. PreviewView uses the `rear` camera > Switch to `front` (> Switch to `rear`)

In each cases the `orientation` of the `UIImage` goes from `up` to `landscape right`. I have tried many solutions from here but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. I'm still getting the images in **wrong orientation** in both cases.

Here's some code:

- Getting image from CMSampleBuffer

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    ...
    let points = modelDataHandler.runModel(onFrame: imagePixelBuffer)
    ...
}

func runModel(onFrame pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> [Corners : CGFloat] {
    ...
    guard let thumbnailPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer.uiImageConverted() else {
        return [:]
    }
    ...
}


extension CVPixelBuffer {
    func uiImageConverted() -> UIImage? {
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: self)
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(self), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(self)))) else { return nil }
        let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return uiImage
    }
}
```

- Setting UIImage to UIImageView

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tfQueue.async { [self] in
        modelDataHandler = ModelDataHandler()
        guard modelDataHandler != nil else {
            fatalError()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            spinnerStack.isHidden = true
            spinner.stopAnimating()
            runButton.isEnabled = true
            runButton.tintColor = .label
            imageView.image = imageInfo?.originalImage.fixedOrientation()
            imageWidth = imageInfo?.originalImage.size.width ?? 0
            imageHeight = imageInfo?.originalImage.size.height ?? 0
        }
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func fixedOrientation() -> UIImage? {
        guard let cImage = cgImage else { return nil }
        let currentOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        let temp = CIImage(cgImage: cImage)
        var ciImage = temp
        switch currentOrientation {
        case .unknown, .portrait:
            ciImage = temp.oriented(forExifOrientation: 6)
        case .landscapeRight:
            ciImage = temp.oriented(forExifOrientation: 3)
        case .landscapeLeft:
            ciImage = temp.oriented(forExifOrientation: 1)
        default:
            break
        }
        
        guard let cgImage = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return nil }
        let fixedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return fixedImage
    }
}
```

How do I fix the orientation problem?

Comment: Orientation problems are common and there are many related posts here. I see you are not setting it in uiImageConverted. Note the other UIImage initializer that takes a scale and orientation.

Comment: @DavidH Yes, it's not correting the orientation in uiImageConverted but even though I am tring to fix it in fixedOrientation(), it doesn't correct it either. The most weird problem is that when I am picking the image from gallery, the orientation is already "up." But when it's set to an UIImageView, it's 90 - 180 degrees rotated. And this happens only for captured images. Downloaded images show correctly.